# How to prevent a component from re-rendering (or atleast keeping state unchanged) when switching pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

If 2 pages have the same component, e.g. a sidebar, how to prevent it from re-rendering when switching between these 2 pages?

To be more specific, the sidebar is at a certain y position in the scroll track. When switching pages, the scroll track y position (and indeed everything else about this sidebar) should remain unchanged.

Comment: Sounds like each page is rendering a sidebar component instead of the parent container of the two pages rendering the sidebar. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: thanks, I think you comment has given me the hint. will report back if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the content of the second page in another HTML file so that  when the user clicks on the link to it, its content gets loaded without refreshing the page (using jQuery). After that, you can change the URL of the page to the second page's URL (using `history.pushState()`). Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#content").load(href);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content" id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <a href="https://link.to.some.url/page/index.html">Visit the next page</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```